# How can I acknowledge a JMS message on another thread and request for redelivery of unacknowledged messages?

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

Step 1:  I need to receive message by one thread.

Step 2:  Process and sending ack and redelivery request (throwing exception) by another thread.

Sample code:

```java
List<Message> list=new ArrayList();

@JmsListener(destination = "${jms.queue-name}", concurrency = "${jms.max-thread-count}")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) throws JMSException,UnsupportedEncodingException {
   list.add(message)
}
  
void run() {
   foreach(Message message:list) {
      //need to send ack or throw exception for redeliver if error
   }
}
```

Now another thread will start and process the list which contains data then how can I send an acknowledgement or throw an exception for redelivery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd let your framework (e.g. Spring) deal with concurrent message processing. This is, in fact, one of the benefits of such frameworks. I don't see any explicit benefit to dumping all the messages into a `List` and then manually spawning a thread to process it. Spring is *already* doing this for you via the `@JmsListener` by invoking `receiveMessage` in a thread and providing configurable concurrency.

Furthermore, if you want to trigger redelivery then you'll need to use a transacted JMS session and invoke `rollback()` but JMS sessions are *not* threadsafe so you'll have to control access to it somehow. This will almost certainly make your code needlessly complex.

Comment: Yes, Its provide the concurrency but the thing is :
 I have to call the other service that can give the response asynchrounsly(means another thread will accept the response of calling thread)
Based on that response I have to acknowledge the message or redelivery request.

If I call the other service inside the receiveMessage then problem can't be solved.

Comment: This "other service" that you're calling must provide a way to receive the response whether that's synchronous or asynchronous. If it's asynchronous then you need to block and wait for the response, and then based on that response you can acknowledge the original JMS message or trigger redelivery. The message is tied to the session and the session is not thread-safe so you can't just be passing it around to different threads. It's going to make your application very fragile and difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks Justin!
Your comment was really helpful. So now I have made changes in application.
I have changed client_ack to auto_ack. At the time of receiving queue message inserted data in DB with status ENQUEUED
And another thread will read DB and update status DEQUEUED then call to other service. Both reading queue and calling other service thread are working independenty.